# Java - Object within an Object

Tags: java

so Ive been trying to set values to an object within an object with no luck. This is what I need to do.

Class 1: Interface (main) With MovieDatabase object

Class 2: MovieDatabase with Movie Object

Class 3: Movie with 4 values needed. Name of movie,director etc.

I've previously only used one object and accessed that through another class but I'm not sure how to do this when it's an object within an object. Any examples using the classes above would be appreciated.

Comment: What you are looking is a Java OO Tutorial/guide. This is not on topic : [help/on-topic]

Comment: can u explain more in generalized way and currently it is looking simple OOPs concept

Comment: You don't need an interface per se imo, and it's really not difficult. You need two classes, Movie with 4 variables, MovieDatabase with at least one variable (an instance of Movie). Best practice is declaring these as private, and using getters (& setters, if needed) to access/modify the data. **I'd recommend reading about encapsulating data, general object-oriented programming etc**. The accessing will be quite easy: `MyMovieDB.getMovie().getDirector()`.

Comment: The thing is that this is for an assignment and i need to have all these classes with the objects in those specific classes mentioned. Im not sure how to approach this. Ive had a look at some composition tutorials but they create the objects in one class only, whereas i need the first object in class 1, second object in class 2. I have already used set/get methods, data encapsulation etc but only with 2 classes, like youve shown.

Comment: Good, now try with more .. we are not going to do this assignment for you, this won't help you. Try and try again. There is a lot of guide (that take more than 10min to read) that will give you a good knowledge to answer this.

Comment: As I said when you [duplicated this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43424759/copying-an-object-thats-in-a-different-class): We cannot help you with code we cannot see. Put a [mcve] in the question, saying clearly what result you want, what you've done to try to get that result, and what *specific* problem you're having doing so. You might also comment on the answer that's here saying why, two days later, it's not solving your problem.

Answer (score 4):

A quick example

> `Movie` Class

```
public class Movie {


    private String name;
    private String director;


    public Movie(String name,String director){

        this.name=name;
        this.director=director;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getDirector() {
        return director;
    }

    public void setDirector(String director) {
        this.director = director;
    } 

}
```

> `MovieDatabase` which contains a list of Movie objects

```
public class MovieDatabase {


    List<Movie> movies = new ArrayList<>();

    public List<Movie> getMovies() {
        return movies;
    }

    public void setMovies(List<Movie> movies) {
        this.movies = movies;
    }


}
```

> Now let's try to create some `Movie` objects and add them to the list
>   of `Movie` objects which is a field in `MovieDatabase` Class

```
    public class stackoverflow {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            // TODO code application logic here

            Movie a,b,c,d;
            MovieDatabase db =  new MovieDatabase();


            a = new Movie("Movie1","Director1");
            b = new Movie("Movie2","Director2");
            c = new Movie("Movie3","Director3");
            d = new Movie("Movie4","Director4");

            db.movies.add(a);
            db.movies.add(b);
            db.movies.add(c);
            db.movies.add(d);


            for(Movie movie : db.movies)

 System.out.println("the movie "+movie.getName()+" is directed by "+movie.getDirector());



        }

    }
```

> The output :
>
> the movie Movie1 is directed by Director1
>
> the movie Movie2 is directed by Director2
>
> the movie Movie3 is directed by Director3
>
> the movie Movie4 is directed by Director4